# Internet explorer 11 : XMLHttpRequest is not defined?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have a object that use this code :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest() ; // Defifned both MF 34+ && IE 10+
xhr.open('GET', webService , true) ;
(...)
Xhr.send(false);
```

Works fine in FireFox and Internet Explorer 10 ... 
and https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp and https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest and everywhere...

But not  with MY Internet Explorer 11, I have a problem.  I use the interactive console (F12).

```
user=> var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
Object doesn't support this action

user=> Typeof XMLHttpRequest
“undefined”
```

How to use a XMLHttpRequest object in IE11?

Comment: Using this from the console makes rather little sense to begin with - for example, there would be no actual origin for the request to come from to begin with. Presumably IE 11 throws that error simply because of that; I guess if you tried that from an actual website context, there would be no problem.

Comment: Not able to reproduce this behavior in ie11

Comment: So the question is which security preference cause this stange behaviour.  Also, properties cannot be added runtime!

Comment: _“So the question is which security preference cause this stange behaviour”_ - probably: None. The strange thing here would rather be that other browsers allow this. But I guess the specification doesn’t specifically consider this “use case” (in quotes, because I’d say it isn’t actually one) of trying to use it from console to begin with ...